# Display: flex not working - how do I create a two-column responsive table?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I'm very new to HTML/CSS, and I've been following this [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/mq0xJxOTiYo?si=ACWOiNu5XqxQbWRJ&t=2524). @42:10 of the video -- When I try the "display: flex" to list the skills in two columns, it just ends up in one column that is center-justified (see screenshot and my code below). I'm wondering does anyone know why it isn't working for me / what I'm doing wrong?

[image: screenshot: one column instead of two! :(]

```css
.skills__content {
  row-gap: 3.5rem;
}

.skills__title {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.skills__box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 3rem;
}

.skills__group {
  display: grid;
  align-content: flex-start;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.skills__data i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__name {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.skills__level {
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
}
```

```html
<div class="skills__content grid" data-content id="skills">
  <div class="skills__area">
    <h3 class="skills__title">
      Front-End Developer
    </h3>

    <div class="skills__box">
      <div class="skills__group">
        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">HTML</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">JavaScript</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">React</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Bootstrap</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Git</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="skills__area">
    <h3 class="skills__title">
      Back-End Developer
    </h3>

    <div class="skills__box">
      <div class="skills__group">
        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Python</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Golang</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Java</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">C++</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">SQL</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex layout is applied at the outermost level of your layout and contains the primary sub-containers. You have it inside several layers of elements. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox. The fix is a little more than I have time for now, but I suggest that you start fresh with a bare layout and add one thing at a time.

Comment: See 37:46. What the video shows is not what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint provided by Alochi above, I was able to fix the bug in my code. Originally, I had grouped all of the skills under one **skills__group** per each **skills_box** -- In order for the flexbox to show two columns, there should be two **skills__group**s per each **skills__box** (see updated HTML code below). Thanks so much for all the help!!

[image]

```css
.skills__content {
  row-gap: 3.5rem;
}

.skills__title {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.skills__box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 3rem;
}

.skills__group {
  display: grid;
  align-content: flex-start;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.skills__data i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__name {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.skills__level {
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
}
```

```html
                    <div class="skills__content grid" data-content id="skills">
                        <div class="skills__area">
                          <h3 class="skills__title">
                            Front-End Developer
                          </h3>

                          <div class="skills__box">
                            <div class="skills__group">
                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">HTML</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">JavaScript</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__group">
                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">React</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Bootstrap</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Git</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="skills__area">
                          <h3 class="skills__title">
                            Back-End Developer
                          </h3>

                          <div class="skills__box">
                            <div class="skills__group">
                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Python</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Golang</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Java</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__group">
                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">C++</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="skills__data">
                                <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

                                <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">SQL</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfect, you have two menus in columns, you just need to add a couple of CSS rules to **skills__content** class to make them appear in rows.

Add another display flex and center it

```css
.skills__content {
  row-gap: 3.5rem;
  display: flex; /* Show in rows */
  justify-content: center;
  gap:20px
}

.skills__title {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.skills__box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 3rem;
}

.skills__group {
  display: grid;
  align-content: flex-start;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.skills__data i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__name {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.skills__level {
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
}
```

```html
<div class="skills__content grid" data-content id="skills">
  <div class="skills__area">
    <h3 class="skills__title">
      Front-End Developer
    </h3>

    <div class="skills__box">
      <div class="skills__group">
        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">HTML</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">JavaScript</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">React</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Bootstrap</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Git</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Intermediate</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="skills__area">
    <h3 class="skills__title">
      Back-End Developer
    </h3>

    <div class="skills__box">
      <div class="skills__group">
        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Python</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Golang</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">Java</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">C++</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Advanced</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills__data">
          <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line"></i>

          <div>
            <h3 class="skills__name">SQL</h3>
            <span class="skills__level">Basic</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```